# Endeca search related services

Tags: endeca

I am new into Endeca,My question is there any search related services in endeca like
1) Autosuggestion web service
2) Category Landing page web service
3) Search Result web service 
for example in ATG we have "ATG RestAPI". if existed these above services, Could you please let me know links and share the docs
I already googling but i did't get proper solution for this.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I believe that endeca does not provides web services for this functionality directly. Experience Manager (layered on top of endeca search) does has a REST API.